# Accessing Spring Data Using JPA Repository

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am creating a RESTful web service where a customer can see all his/her orders for a particular month/week or any date range. I am using Spring-Boot, Spring Data, JPA, Hibernate and in memory database h2. I have gotten all the dependencies using Maven.

I have two classes named customer and orders. A customer can have multiple orders that means there is One To Many relationship between them. I have pre populated the customer and orders table in database and on localhost://h2/console I am able to see the tables and data. I have mapped customers to orders with OneToMany relationship.

First, I am trying to get all orders of a customer by his first name.

Here's my Customer Entity:

```
@Entity
```

public class Customer {

```
@Id
private Integer customer_id;
private String customer_first_name;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Customer_Orders> customerOrders;


protected Customer() {

}


public Customer(Integer customer_id, String customer_first_name) {
    super();
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
    this.customer_first_name = customer_first_name;
}

public Integer getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomer_id(Integer customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}

public String getCustomer_first_name() {
    return customer_first_name;
}

public void setCustomer_first_name(String customer_first_name) {
    this.customer_first_name = customer_first_name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer [customer_id=" + customer_id + ", customer_first_name=" + customer_first_name + "]";
}
```

Here's is my CustomerRepository class:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer>{

    List<Customer_Orders> findAllByFirstName(String customer_first_name);

}
```

Here's my CustomerService class:

```
@Service
public class CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        super();
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }


    public List<Customer_Orders> findAllFirstName(String customer_first_name) {
        return customerRepository.findAllByFirstName(customer_first_name);
    }

}
```

Here's my CustomerController class:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerResource {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private CustomerService customerService;


    @GetMapping("/customers/orders/{customer_first_name}")
    public List<Customer_Orders> findAllByFirstName(@PathVariable(value="customer_first_name") String customer_first_name) {
        return customerService.findAllFirstName(customer_first_name);
    }

}
```

When I run an application, I am getting following stack trace.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.shiptTest.jpa.ShiptTakeHomeTest.customer.CustomerRepository.findAllByFirstName(java.lang.String)! No property firstName found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.shiptTest.jpa.ShiptTakeHomeTest.ShiptTakeHomeTestApplication.main(ShiptTakeHomeTestApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customerRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.shiptTest.jpa.ShiptTakeHomeTest.customer.CustomerRepository.findAllByFirstName(java.lang.String)! No property firstName found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.shiptTest.jpa.ShiptTakeHomeTest.customer.CustomerRepository.findAllByFirstName(java.lang.String)! No property firstName found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:555) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:540) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:540) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:319) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property firstName found for type Customer!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:350) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:330) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:283) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:265) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:248) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you format the stacktrace ?

Comment: Have you simply **read** the error message? What is unclear in *"No property firstName found for type Customer!*"? Also, why do you think a method named `findAllByFirstName`, located in a `Repository<Customer>`, should return a `List<Customer_Orders>`. You don't go to a garage to buy an ice cream. So don't go to a Repository<Customer> to find Customer_Orders. And respect the Java naming conventions: CustomerOrder, firstName, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use

```
private String firstName;
```

instead of

```
private String customer_first_name;
```

and 
use  @Autowired on the service :

```
@RestController
public class CustomerResource {


   // private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;


    @GetMapping("/customers/orders/{customer_first_name}")
    public List<Customer_Orders> findAllByFirstName(String customer_first_name) {
        return customerService.findAllFirstName(customer_first_name);
    }

}
```

and you can delete constructor in Service Class :

```
 @Service
    public class CustomerService {

        @Autowired
        private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

        public List<Customer_Orders> findAllFirstName(String customer_first_name) {
            return customerRepository.findAllByFirstName(customer_first_name);
        }

    }
```

finally you should scan the service :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="*****" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try method name findByFirstName(...). Spring data will return all the matching entities. The point is that in the entity you are supposed to have a field

private String firstName;

In other words, if the fild's name is fieldName, you declare a method findByFieldName()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Spring Data Jpa expect that your `Customer` has a property named `firstName`. This is because you have a method `CustomerRepository.findAllByFirstName`. But in your entity the field is named `customer_first_name`.

I recommend to rename the field in the entity so that it match java best pratice style guide (camel case instead of using undersores for normal fields) : `customerFirstName`. The rename the method in `CustomerRepository` so that is match the field name: `CustomerRepository.findAllByCustomerFirstName`

The other way would been using a [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) annotation to `CustomerRepository.findAllByFirstName`: `@Query("select c from customer c where c.customer_first_name = ?1")`

Comment: I have added Customer Entity in the question.